# Installing a new Aluminum branch circuit. Do I need to use antioxidant grease?

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker, aluminum-wiring

I am installing a new branch circuit for an electric range (current range is gas).  The only difference between this and all the other electrical work I've done is this will be the first time I've used Al wire in a residential branch circuit.  I just need a quick sanity check to make sure I am doing everything correctly before I proceed.

- Breaker is a Square D [HOM240](https://www.se.com/us/en/product/HOM240/mini-circuit-breaker-homeline-40a-2-pole-120-240vac-10ka-air-standard-type-plug-in-ul/)
- Wire is Al (brand new 2022-manufactured AA-8000) 6-6-6-6 SER
- Recept is a [Utilitech NEMA 14-50R](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Utilitech-Black-50-Amp-Round-Range-Industrial-Range/3775483)
- Load calc already done and I have verified that I'm OK adding the load to this panel

The terminals on both recept and breaker are rated Al/Cu and 75C so I have no qualms about that.  I own (and use) a torque driver, so no qualms there either.  The wire is 90C (derating to 75C still allows #6 for 40A), so I am good there.

The one thing I'm unsure of and need the sanity check on is the use of grease/paste.  I keep reading that you need to use antioxidant paste on Al wire connections, but does that apply to this situation as well, or is that just for the old stuff and dissimilar metal connections?

Comment: One of the pros will jump on here but in my experience you only need antioxidant paste or alumiconn type connectors when you are connecting aluminum wiring directly to copper wiring which it doesn't sound like you are doing in this situation.

Comment: My electricians put noalox on all the terminals in my new meter-main and the two sub panels the AL wire ran to. When I asked the inspector, he said that yes, even though the wire & terminals were both AL, they needed goop on them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's mandatory, UL will require the instructions say so, and I believe UL also will require the terminals come pre-packed with it.

So check the instructions, and if it *already has* noalox, and you somehow remove it, renew the supply.

Otherwise totally optional, your call.  UL doesn't think it's necessary and it's their job to worry about that.

Comment: Does seem to include the possibility of instructions requiring but not being pre-filled. But then, it's code, not UL, so perhaps UL does. Otherwise, clarity indeed. https://www.electricallicenserenewal.com/Electrical-Continuing-Education-Courses/NEC-Content.php?sectionID=1407.0